# How do i check for a specific exact match value in each array that is held within another array? Python

Tags: python, arrays, duplicates, matching

Hi this is my first question here, so a quick background is that I am trying to do a de-duplication process over a large excel file of names and other pieces of data. I extracted it to be an array of arrays.

So **arr[0]** would hold the contents of that one person and  **arr[0][1]** would hold the last name.

I am having trouble finding a way to see if I have duplicated last names in my array PER entry.

my current code is basically like this for the condition checking

```
if(arr[x][1] in full_arr)
```

However it seems that I am getting way more entries than I should be. Is the Python "in" looking at partials too in other areas of the array? like **arr[0][3]** holds emails.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: have a try with [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `zip` and `set` to check if there is a duplicate in a specific row of your multidimensionnal array:

```
if len(list(zip(*arr))[1]) != len(set(list(zip(*arr))[1])):
    #if there is at least one duplicate: do some stuff
```

`set` remove the duplicate, so if `len(set(array)) != len(array)` it means that array have some duplicates.

The `*` operator unpack your array into positional argument: `list(zip(a[0],a[1],a[2],...))` is the same as `list(zip(*a))`